# Cisco 1841 Router from STATIC to DYNAMIC Configuration

Tags: cisco, dhcp

[Basic PC-to-Internet Ethernet Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMorV.jpg)

I'm trying to find the proper configuration in the IOS to have **Fa0/0 = DHCP** and **Fa0/1 = STATIC-only**, to allow packets from the STATIC side (inside network) to move through the Modem (not shown), onto the DYNAMIC side and finally the INTERNET and vise-versa afterwards once my ACL is in place. The problem I'm having is the packets won't leave out of the 1841 to the Internet. Is this possible with this type of router? How?

Ex: Access to/from port 80 to visit a remote webpage for surfing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND THE ANSWER

## Cisco 1841 Router Configuration guide - Fa0/0 = DHCP, Fa0/1 = STATIC

**STATIC-to-DHCP (Dynamic):**

http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26088026-Config-Need-help-configuring-1841-for-lan-broadband-please

---

**DHCP-to-DHCP (Dynamic):**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEYwIvQImPQ (yusofyaghi90)

---

I will try and post a step-by-step compilation update explaining the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is really basic configuration. What have you tried? What is your current configuration? You say that packets are not leaving your router, but are you sure about that? If it is so, them maybe you do not have a static default route, but it might be that packets are going out but not coming back because your router is not doing PAT correctly or at all.

You can look start with http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/12-4t/dhcp-12-4t-book/config-dhcp-client.html